# How do I avoid returning a null value while avoiding mutation?

Tags: java-8

I am trying to create a method that will take a list of items with set weights and choose 1 at random. My solution was to use a Hashmap that will use Integer as a weight to randomly select 1 of the Keys from the Hashmap. The keys of the HashMap can be a mix of Object types and I want to return 1 of the selected keys.

However, I would like to avoid returning a `null` value on top of avoiding mutation. Yes, I know this is Java, but there are more elegant ways to write Java and hoping to solve this problem as it stands.

```
public <T> T getRandomValue(HashMap<?, Integer> VALUES) {
        final int SIZE = VALUES.values().stream().reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b);
        final int RAND_SELECTION = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(SIZE) + 1;
        int currentWeightSum = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<?, Integer> entry : VALUES.entrySet()) {
            if (RAND_SELECTION > currentWeightSum && RAND_SELECTION <= (currentWeightSum + entry.getValue())) {
                return (T) entry.getKey();
            } else {
                currentWeightSum += entry.getValue();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: First check if list is null and wrap the result in Optional. So you got an object back and maybe with some values and easy to check. But in Java returning null and checking value + reacting if null is normal so maybe think about avoiding null

Answer (score 2):

Since the code after the loop should never be reached under normal circumstances, you should indeed not write something like `return null` at this point, but rather throw an exception, so that irregular conditions can be spotted right at this point, instead of forcing the caller to eventually debug a `NullPointerException`, perhaps occurring at an entirely different place.

```
public static <T> T getRandomValue(Map<T, Integer> values) {
    if(values.isEmpty())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    final int totalSize = values.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
    if(totalSize<=0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("sum of weights is "+totalSize);
    final int threshold = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(totalSize) + 1;
    int currentWeightSum = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<T, Integer> entry : values.entrySet()) {
        currentWeightSum += entry.getValue();
        if(threshold <= currentWeightSum) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    // if we reach this point, the map's content must have been changed in-between
    throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
}
```

Note that the code fixes some other issues of your code. You should not promise to return an arbitrary `T` without knowing the actual type of the map. If the map contains objects of different type as key, i.e. is a `Map<Object,Integer>`, the caller can’t expect to get anything more specific than `Object`. Besides that, you should not insist of the parameter to be a `HashMap` when any `Map` is sufficient. Further, I changed the variable names to adhere to Java’s naming convention and simplified the loop’s body.

If you want to support empty maps as legal input, changing the return type to `Optional<T>` would be the best solution, returning an empty optional for empty maps and an optional containing the value otherwise (this would disallow `null` keys). Still, the supposed-to-be-unreachable code point after the loop should be flagged with an exception.